# Sending SMS using Twilio from my website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to send SMS from twilio account. Here is my code.

```
try 
{  
    string ACCOUNT_SID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];  
    string AUTH_TOKEN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];  

    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);  
    client.SendSmsMessage("+1XXXXXXXXXX", "+1XXXXXXXXXXX", "Hi");    
    Label1.Text = "Sent Successfully";    
 }  
 catch (Exception ex) 
 {  
    Label1.Text = "Error:"+ex.Message;  
 }
```

Running on my server, I am receiving message "Sent Successfully" but not receiving message on my phone.

I have changed the original numbers with "XXXXX".Also I have added packages for Twilio.

Please let me know if can.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You might be getting an error back from the Twilio REST API when you make the call to SendSmsMessage.  You can check if this is happening by grabbing the value returned from the method and seeing if the RestException property is null or not:

```
var result = client.SendSmsMessage("+1xxxxxxxxxx", "+1xxxxxxxxxx", "Hi");
if (result.RestException!=null)
{
    //An error occured
    Console.Writeline(result.RestException.Message);
}
```

Another option would be to use a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to watch the actual HTTP request/response as it happens and see if any errors are happening.

Hope that helps.